# Massaging data for charts?

Tags: javascript, php, charts, bar-chart

I am creating some bar charts for a client application. The problem I am having is that the data consists mostly of small values, but there are few large values that are basically destroying the visualization.

Some examples of values:

```
96,942,535,341 
23,598 
1,219,203 
958,201
100,654
112,911
```

I have a max height of 250 pixels to work with. So, right now I find the largest value in the data set and set that to the max height. I then calculate a pixel / value ratio for the rest of the values. If you do the math, you will see that the other bars don't even make it to 1 pixel!

Does anyone have any suggestions on a better way to calculate these ratios to make the charts work visually...or am I sunk?

I am using php on the backend to do the calculations and javascript routines for creating the charts on the fly.

Comment: You need to ask yourself what the charts are trying to convey. When you know this you will probably know how to visualize it. E.g. it seems likely that you can skip those large values, or just cut them off at the max height and let the user know that they continue beyond the frame.

Comment: Use a log scale? (Not very common in a bar chart, though...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

- Use a [logarithmic scale](https://xkcd.com/1162/).
- Take an arbitrary value between the maximum value and the average value and take that as the max height of your chart. This effectively "cuts off" the large values. Unfortunately this one requires quite a lot of trial and error to find the sweet spot and depends largely on the kind of data you have.

Comment: Hmm. That could get sticky since the data is dynamic.

Comment: I agree, _sticky_ is the appropriate term to use here. Thinking about it, I'd propose something like `min( (avg*x), max )` with x somewhere between `2` and `Inf` depending on how much of the large bars you want to show.

Comment: Well, just using the standard log() function in php at least makes the visualization work a bit better. However, I think I am going to try your latest suggestion. I assume that x would be a number between max and the avg, correct? Would it be better to start in the middle of those values?

Comment: Phew, 3 times the average of all values might be a [good starting point](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thirds)?